# Is there ever a reason to use an array when lists are available?

Tags: c#, data-types

It seems like `List<T>` in C# can do everything an array can do and more, and seems also just as efficient in memory and performance as an array.

So why would I ever want to use an array?

I'm obviously not asking about cases where an API or other external constraint (i.e. the Main function) requires me to use an array... I'm only asking about creating new data structures in my own code.

Comment: To implement `List<T>`

Comment: Funny.... but... considering I already have the .Net framework to work with

Comment: `is also just as efficient in memory and performance as an array` - um. Where did you get that notion from?

Comment: Multiple dimensions like `var test = new string[5,5]` ;)

Comment: It allows List<T> to *not* be a built-in type and allows the simpler type `T[]` (no resizing, only length and data) be the built-in type

Comment: @Knerd: Why not have lists of lists `List<List<String>>`?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner they aren't guaranteed to be rectangular

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Hmm maybe create a subclass of List that has a size constraint on the maximum number of elements in it `ConstrainedList<ConstrainedList<String>(5)>(5)`... Seems like a lot more trouble than it's worth, but it would probably work. ;)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner What about `int[,,,,]` make that with `List<List<List<List<List<int>>>>>` looks ugly ;)

Comment: @Knerd then it's time to create a multidimensional list

Comment: @ratchetfreak https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Experimental.Collections

Comment: There's also the commonly used byte[] array.

Comment: For C# specifically, Eric Lippert wrote about this in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx.

Comment: Allowing `Add` and `Remove` could also be seen as a bug if the data NEEDS to be a fixed size. Another loss for `List<T>`.

Comment: @ratchet freak Is `List<T>` in C always an array list??

Comment: @InstructedA in C# it is.

Comment: Pretty much already discussed here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434761/array-versus-listt-when-to-use-which

Comment: Yes, there's one at least: to tech students how to use arrays.

Comment: I'm no expert on C#: does it support Lists containing _primitives_?  (A Google search was surprisingly useless).  If not, then, as in Java, there may be significant performance and memory advantages to using arrays for _large amounts_ of primitives, e.g. tens of thousands of 4-byte ints or floats as opposed to tens of thousands of around 20 byte wrapper Objects.

Comment: In high-performance situations, there are [some things to consider](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/844781/Digging-Into-NET-Loop-Performance-Bounds-checking), though this is a very particular set of concerns not really applicable to the "right tool for the job" decision in most scenarios.

Comment: @user949300: there are no primitives in C#.

Comment: @user949300: yes, `List<T>` stores unboxed `int`, `char`, `double` etc.

Answer (score 31):

The same reason I don't drive a truck when going to work. I don't use something that I won't use the features of.

First of all an array is a primitive construct so an array is faster and more efficient than a List<> for sure, so your argument is not true. Array is also available everywhere and known by developers using different languages and platforms.

The most important reason I use an array instead of a List<> is to imply that the data is **fixed length**. If I won't add or remove any items from that data collection, I want to make sure that the type reflects that.

Another thing is let's say you are implementing a new data structure and you've read some papers about it. Now while implementing specific algorithms, you can't always rely on someone else's implementation of a type that is general purpose. It changes from .NET to Mono and even between different versions of the framework.

And it is sometimes easier to port a piece of code that uses an array instead of a framework dependent type.

Comment: How is an array "faster" than a list, considering that `List<T>` is implemented using an array? If you know the element count beforehand (which you have to know, when using an array), you can use that knowledge when initializing the list as well.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis When using an array we allocate the memory and simply make assignments, plain malloc(), no overhead. When you are using List<> you will "Add" items and when adding items List<> makes some boundary checking and calls EnsureCapacity method which will copy the contents to another newly allocated array if the current capacity is not enough. It means if you don't need to dynamically allocate new memory, List's performance is not as good as array.

Comment: What you're saying is correct, but it assumes that either we don't know the element count beforehand (in which case, arrays aren't useful anyway) or that we *do* know the element count beforehand but we deliberately don't use it in the case of the list. If we *do* use the element count to initialize the list with the desired capacity, we get only one array allocation (until you reach that capacity), thus we pay the same performance costs. All other common operations are equal (search, retrieval by index, assignment by index), except for further adds (which arrays don't have at all).

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: Arrays **are** faster than lists. Just run a simple benchmark to check.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis, Yes, but there are still boundary checks.

Comment: I'll take your word for it, although I don't understand exactly how simple explicit boundary checks can add up quite as much. At least it's good to know that there is an observable difference, it makes it easier to choose one or the other (in scenarios where they would otherwise seem interchangeable). Cheers!

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis The extra overhead usually isn't noticeable, but it can matter for very specific use cases (numeric code that spends most of its time multiplying arrays of numbers). That said, C# arrays have their own bounds checks and such libraries are sometimes implemented in C to get around that.

Comment: @Mert: I believe (almost certain) that boundary checks are removed by the compilers when the usage is *obviously correct* such as in a loop with correct end checks.

Comment: @ZanLynx Thanks for reminding. My point was that a wrapper object is heavier and slower than a wrapped object. And as you know, compiler optimizations are not standard accross different implementations and platforms. I don't really care about small performance differences but I wanted to mention it theoretically.

Answer (score 19):

You need arrays to manage your collection of **mutable structs**, of course, and what would we do without those.

```
struct EvilMutableStruct { public double X; } // don't do this

EvilMutableStruct[] myArray = new EvilMutableStruct[1];
myArray[0] = new EvilMutableStruct()
myArray[0].X = 1; // works, this modifies the original struct

List<EvilMutableStruct> myList = new List<EvilMutableStruct>();
myList.Add(new EvilMutableStruct());
myList[0].X = 1; // does not work, the List will return a *copy* of the struct
```

*(note that there may be some cases where an array of mutable struct is desireable, but usually this differing behavior of mutable structs within arrays versus other collections is a source of errors that should be avoided)*

---

More seriously, you need an array if you want to **pass an element by reference**. i.e.

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref myArray[i]);  // works
Interlocked.Increment(ref myList[i]);   // does not work, you can't pass a property by reference
```

That can be useful for lock-free threadsafe code.

---

You need an array if you quickly and efficiently want to **initialize** your fixed-size collection **with the default value**.

```
double[] myArray = new double[1000]; // contains 1000 '0' values
                                     // without further initialisation

List<double> myList = new List<double>(1000) // internally contains 1000 '0' values, 
                                             // since List uses an array as backing storage, 
                                             // but you cannot access those
for (int i =0; i<1000; i++) myList.Add(0);   // slow and inelegant
```

*(note that it would be possible to implement a constructor for List that does the same, it's just that c# does not offer this feature)*

---

you need an array if you want to **efficiently copy** parts of the collection

```
Array.Copy(array1, index1, array2, index2, length) // can't get any faster than this

double[,] array2d = new double[10,100];
double[] arraySerialized = new double[10*100];
Array.Copy(array2d, 0, arraySerialized, 0, arraySerialized.Length);
// even works for different dimensions
```

*(again, this is something that could be implemented for List as well, but this feature does not exist in c#)*

Comment: If a type is supposed to represent a group of related-but-independent variables stuck together with duct tape (e.g. the coordinates of a point), an exposed-field struct is the best representation. If a variable is supposed to hold a bunch of such groups, an array of that structure type is the best representation. One shouldn't use mutable structs in places where one wants an object, but that doesn't mean one should use objects or things that pretend to be objects in places where one wants a bunch of variables stuck together with duct tape.

Comment: There are some situations where you may want a mutable struct, such as when you need the last bit of performance and cannot afford heap allocations and references, and in that case an array of structs is your best bet. [Good essay here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2006/08/31/performance-quiz-11-ten-questions-on-value-based-programming.aspx). But I would disagree that a class should not represent "a bunch of variables stuck together". Conceptually structs and classes are mostly the same, the differences are primarily because of implementation details.

Comment: If one wishes to use a collection of mutable-object references as a collection of independent groups of independent variables, one must establish and maintain an invariant that each element identifies an object to which no other non-ephemeral references exist anywhere in the universe. That can certainly be done (and often is), but there is nothing in the language or framework to assist the programmer in upholding that invariant.  By contrast, a length-100 array of a structure type with four instance fields will automatically and permanently encapsulate 400 independent variables.

Comment: I think these comments are the wrong place to discuss this issue further, and seeing as you added [your own answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/265116/72321), there does not seem to be a need to duplicate this information here. Suffice to say, arrays can be used for managing mutable structs. Whether and when to use the implementation behaviour of those structs to enforce certain data constraints really goes beyond the scope of my answer.

Comment: Mutable structs are not evil. Wherever you got this notion from, it's wrong.

Answer (score 15):

> So why would I ever want to use an array?

*Rarely*, you will have a scenario where you *know* that you need a fixed number of elements. From a design perspective, this should be avoided. If you need 3 things, the nature of business means that you'll very often need 4 in the next release.

Still, when this rare scenario actually occurs, using an array to enforce that fixed size invariant is useful. It provides a signal to other programmers that it is a fixed size, and helps prevent misuse where someone adds or removes an element - breaking expectations elsewhere in code.

Comment: or until you need to reset the position of all data anyway, like during a rehash of a hashtable.

Comment: @ratchetfreak - eh? This isn't clear.

Comment: For a hash table you can use an array and when you need to grow the table you need to set the elements to the new positions based on `hash%newArray.length` anyway.

Comment: The size of arrays is not set in stone at the time one writes code. It can, and often is, a run-time variable. It just never changes *after the array has been created*.

Comment: It's not unusual to deal with a fixed number of elements. If you're working with 3D points, you probably won't be working with 5D points at any point in the future. The bigger issues with arrays is that they're mutable and don't have convenient labels attached to their elements.

Comment: @Doval `List<T>` fixes neither of these issues.

Comment: @JanDvorak Lists can shrink or grow and thus don't make sense in any context involving a fixed number of elements.

Comment: Rarely? Not everyone works on super-complicated ultra-configurable enterprise monstrosities.

Comment: @whatsisname - I've worked on a wide variety of apps for a wide variety of industries. Array use is of course more common in some places, but it's always different shades of rare compared to `List` (or other collections) (in my experience).

Comment: It is very common to have a fixed number of elements. Just make sure the length is defined by a constant, so when the next release increase the number of elements from 3 to 4, you just change the constant and everything that relies on this is adapted.

Comment: @Hans Considering this question is about C#, if you're defining a constant for your array length you're very likely doing something wrong. [`Array.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length.aspx) should be used pretty much everywhere you access it if you ever expect a changing length.

Comment: It would be easy to make a subclass for fixed-sized lists. The necessity of fixed sizes alone does not justify a significant change of convention.

Comment: @raptortech97 - without violating LSP?

Comment: @Telastyn oh, I don't generally follow the LSP. You should be able to make a second class that would be very similar but not allow size-changing operations. I don't know the best way to implement it; I think the Java Collections, for example, do sometimes violate the LSP. Perhaps a List<T> would contain a FixedSizeList<T> and add functionality on top of that, replacing the underlying fixed size list as necessary. Regardless, you could have a FixedSizeList<T> instead of T[].

Comment: @Bob: Yes when accessing the array you should always use the length, however when you have fixed length arrays in a project there are often other places that also relies on that number, and even if not, it is good practice to keep a set of constants together that defines the "metrics" of your project.

Comment: @raptortech97 LSP is quite possibly the most important principle not to break, because it always results in incorrect behavior when broken, whereas the rest generally just incur technical debt. Java Collections don't break LSP, they just have very loose contracts. e.g. `clear()` is optional and may throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. You *could* make a `FixedSizeList` which implements `IList`, but it should never be a subclass of `List`.

Answer (score 11):

Your question has actually [already been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/454923).

> and seems also just as efficient in memory and performance as an array.

It isn't. From the question I linked:

```
List/foreach:  3054ms (589725196)
Array/foreach: 1860ms (589725196)
```

Arrays are twice as fast in certain important cases. I am certain the memory usage also differs non-trivially.

Since the main premise of your question is thus defeated, I'm assuming this answers your question. In addition to this, sometimes arrays are forced on you by Win32 API, or your GPU's shader, or some other non-DotNet library.

Even within DotNet, some methods consume and/or return arrays (such as `String.Split`). Which means either you must now eat the cost of calling `ToList` and `ToArray` all the time, or you must conform and use array, possibly continuing the cycle by propagating this to poor downstream users of *your* code.

More questions and answers on Stack Overflow on this topic:

- [Array versus `List<T>`: When to use which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434761/array-versus-listt-when-to-use-which)
- [Why do we use arrays instead of other data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392397/why-do-we-use-arrays-instead-of-other-data-structures)
- [Which is better to use array or `List<>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975426/which-is-better-to-use-array-or-list)

Comment: Interestingly, that answer points out that if you use old-fashioned indexed loops (**for** instead of **foreach**) the performance difference is minimal.

Answer (score 3):

This actually goes for other languages which have lists as well (such as Java or Visual Basic). There are cases where you need to use an array because a method returns an array instead of a List.

In an actual program, I don't think an array will be used very often, but sometimes you know the data will be a fixed size and you like the small performance gain you get from using an array. Micro-optimisation would be a valid reason, just as a method returning a list, or the need for a multidimensional datastructure.

Comment: Many languages don't even have separate list and array collections.  On the other hand, using `list<T>` where `vector<T>` will work is a disastrously bad idea in C/C++.

Comment: "Because a method returns an array" -- this is a misfeature of Java, forcing programmers to crap up the code with "Arrays.asList(x)".  T[] should at least implement Iterable<T>

Comment: @StevenBurnap - it certainly is disastrously bad in C, because there's no way to compile that code.

Comment: @PeteBecker The expression `vector<T> x` [compiles just fine for me in C](http://ideone.com/dZIZfJ). :-)

Comment: Sorry, I meant the C hand-rolled equivalent to `list<T>`.  Basically, I've seen lots of performance problems caused by developers just using lists by default when an array was a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to reasons listed in other answers, array literal takes fewer characters to declare:

```
var array = new [] { "A", "B", "C" };
var list = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };
```

Using array instead of `List` makes the code a bit shorter and just a bit more readable in cases when (1) you  need to pass any `IEnumerable<T>` literal, or (2) where other functionality of `List` doesn't matter and you need to use some list-like literal.

I've done this occasionally in unit tests.

Comment: Yes just to add. It also works of you need to pass an IList <T>

Comment: +1, often I have some operation for a couple of objects of the same type which are not in a collection. It's easy, short and clear to write `foreach( var x in new []{ a, b, c ) ) DoStuff( x )` or `new []{ a, b, c ).Select( ... )` etc

Answer (score 3):

This is strictly from an OO perspective.

While I can't think of a reason to pass just an array around, I can certainly see situations where an array representation internal to the class is probably the best choice.

While there are other options that give similar characteristics, none seem as intuitive as an array for problems dealing with processing permutations, nested for loops, matrix representation, bitmaps and data interleaving algorithms.

There's a substantial number of scientific fields that rely on matrix math extensively. (e.g. image processing, data error correction, digital signal processing, a ream of applied mathematics problems). Most of the algorithms in those fields are written in terms of using multidimensional arrays/matrixes. So it would be more natural to implement the algorithms as they are defined rather than make them more "software" friendly at the expense of losing the direct tie-ins to the papers the algorithms are based upon.

Like I said, in these cases you can probably get away with using lists but that adds yet another layer of complexity on top of what are already complex algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a use for arrays in a game I have been writing. I used it for creating an inventory system with a fixed number of slots. This had several benefits:

1. I knew exactly how many open inventory slots the game object had by looking and seeing which slots were null.
2. I knew exactly what index each item was in.
3. It was still a "typed" array (Item[] Inventory), so I could add/remove the objects of type "Item".

I figured that if I ever needed to "increase" the size of the inventory, I could do so by transferring the old items into the new array, but since the inventory was fixed by screen space and I had no need to dynamically make it larger/smaller, it worked well for the purpose I was using it for.

Answer (score 1):

If you're traversing all elements of a list, then no, an array is not necessary, 'next' or arbitrary 'selection without replacement' will do fine.

But if your algorithm needs random access to the elements in the collection, then, yes, an array is necessary.

This is somewhat analogous to "is goto necessary?". In a reasonable modern language it is not needed at all. But if you peel away the abstractions, at some point, that's all that is actually available to you, that is, the only way to implement these abstractions is with the  'unnecessary' feature. (Of course, the analogy isn't perfect, I don't think anyone says that arrays are poor programming practice; they are easy to understand and think about).

Comment: List<T> also offers random access. Sure, it's *implemented* with an array, but that doesn't need to bother you, the user. So at best, you offered a single reason to use arrays: To implement `List<T>`.

Comment: @delnan I think that's my point with respect to abstractions. Sometimes it is better to think in terms of an array, not just for efficiency reasons. (of course sometimes it is way better to think of a linked list, and way better than that to think of a list (without caring about links or otherwise how it is implemented), and way better just a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Legacy compatibility.

All form personal experience:

Legacy programmers - my colleague uses arrays everywhere, has done for 30+ years, good luck changing his mind with your new fangled ideas.

Legacy code - foo(array bar[]) sure you can use a list/vector/collection toarray function but if you not using any of there additional features its easier to use an array to begin with, often more readable without the type switching.

Legacy boss - my boss was a good programmer before she went into management many years ago and still thinks she's up to date, "were using arrays" can end a meeting, explaining what a collection is can cost everyone lunch.

Comment: colleagues that are 20 years behind the curve and a boss that wants to know what data types you're using... I love this site for reminding myself how much worse my job could be

Comment: about 40% of what we do is embedded design where discussions are held in KB, he likes to tell me hes not outdated hes specalised lol

Answer (score 0):

1)  There is no multi-dimensional version of List.  If your data has more than one dimension it will be very inefficient to use lists.

2)  When you are dealing with a large number of small data types (say, a map where all you have is one byte for the terrain type) there can be considerable performance differences due to caching.  The array version loads several items per memory read, the list version loads only one.  Furthermore, the array version holds several times as many cells in the cache as the list version--if you're repeatedly processing the data this can make a big difference if the array version fits in cache but the list version does not.

For an extreme case, consider Minecraft.  (Yeah, it's not written in C#.  The same reason applies.)

Comment: Actually, .Net is weird in this regard: [multidimensional arrays (e.g. `T[,]`) are slower than the equivalent jagged arrays (e.g. `T[][]`)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/468832/41071).

Answer (score 0):

A 100-element array of some type T encapsulates 100 independent variables of type T.  If T happens to be a value type which has a mutable public field of type Q and one of type R, then each element of the array will encapsulate independent variables of types Q and R.  The array as a whole will thus encapsulate 100 independent variables of type Q and 100 independent variables of type R; any of those variables may be accessed individually without affecting any other.  *No collection type other than arrays can allow the fields of structures to be used as independent variables.*

If T happened instead to be a class type with public mutable fields of type Q and R, each element of the array holds the *only* reference, anywhere in the universe, to an instance of `T`, and if none of the elements of the array will ever be modified to identify an object to which any outside reference exists, then the array will effectively encapsulate 100 independent variables of type Q and 100 independent variables of type R.  Other collection types can mimic the behavior of such an array, but if the only purpose of the array is to encapsulate 100 variables of type Q and 100 of type R, encapsulating each pair of variables in its own class object is an expensive way of doing that. Further, *using an array or collection of mutable class type creates the possibility that the variables identified by array elements may not be independent*.

If a type is supposed to behave like some kind of object, then it should either be a class type or a private-field structure which provides no means of mutation other than replacement.  If, however, a type is supposed to behave like a bunch of related-but-independent variables stuck together with duct tape, then one should use a type which *is* a bunch of variables stuck together with duct tape--an exposed-field struct.  Arrays of such types are very efficient to work with, and have very clean semantics.  Use of any other type will lead to muddled semantics, inferior performance, or both.

Answer (score 0):

One important different is memory allocation. For example, traversing a linked list could result in a lot of cache misses and slower performance, whereas an array represents a contiguous chunk of memory holding multiple instances of some particular data type, and do traversing it in order is more likely to hit the CPU cache.

Of course, an array of object references may not benefit as much from cache hits, since dereferencing could still take you anywhere in memory.

Then there are list implementations such as ArrayList, which implement a list using an array. They're useful primitives to have.

Comment: The question specifically asks about the .Net type `List<T>`, which is not implemented using a linked list, but using an array (it's essentially equivalent to `ArrayList<T>` in Java).

Answer (score -2):

Here's some guidance you can use on when to select `Array` and when to select `List`.

- Use `Array` when returning from a method.
- Use `List` as the variable when you are constructing the return value (inside the method). Then use `.ToArray()` when returning from the method.

In general, use an `Array` when you don't intend the consumer to add items to the collection. Use `List` when you intend the consumer to add items to the collection.

`Array` is meant for dealing with "static" collections while `List` is meant for dealing with "dynamic" collections.

Comment: The rule you suggest is arbitrary and likely to result in inefficient code that performs unnecessary copying. At the very least you need some form of justification for it.

Comment: @Jules I've found developer experience to be much more important than micro-optimizations. I never have performance problems on this level.

Comment: I don't see how the developer experience is improved by this rule, however. It requires you to guess what clients of your code are going to want to do with returned values, and makes your code less convenient to use when you get it wrong, and yet I fail to see any advantage at all to it. Performance may be a secondary concern, but I wouldn't sacrifice it to follow a rule that gains nothing.

Comment: @Jules I guess it comes down to your own preference then. I prefer to treat return values as constants, as such I prefer to use `Array` instead of `List`. Nice to hear your thoughts though!

Comment: Have you considered using UmmodifiableLists?